# Web API2 Serialization exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api2 application which I have scaffolded using EF.

I am trying to serialize the following class (Which contains lazy loaded navigation properties):

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Speciality
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SpecialityId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MedicalFacility> MedicalFacilities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The is my controller:

```
namespace FindAMedicService.Controllers
{

    public class SpecialitiesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: api/Specialities
        public IQueryable<Speciality> GetSpeciality()
        {
            return db.Speciality;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access this particular service to get a list of "Specialities", I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Speciality_DC264D6DBBAF52FB19E27F20DCC47DA1141620CEC0CCAF6E2DEF4D8907FA7C8C' with data contract name 'Speciality_DC264D6DBBAF52FB19E27F20DCC47DA1141620CEC0CCAF6E2DEF4D8907FA7C8C:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at WriteArrayOfSpecialityToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

I didn't have this error before when I did not have the two navigation properties in my Speciality class (Doctors, MedicalFacilities).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try `return db.Speciality.ToList();`?

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick recap - why are you returning `IQueryable` and your entity model as a result?

In my opinion you should transform your entity model to some kind of DTO with only needed properties + change action signature to `IEnumerable<T>`.

What serializer doesn't know is how to serialize dynamic proxies EF creates for your `virtual` properties.

Comment: Thanks.  I just used IQueryable as it was scaffolded as such and it used to work before.  
But to your point of serializing virtual properties.  Is it then possible to send such classes containing other classes?  Should I remove the virtual? Or add a .include statement to explicitly add the navigation properties?

Comment: @NormanBentley You should provide some kind of transformation from entity model to the result object. Entities are often very heavy once materialized and I believe you don't need all their properties. Eager loading is an option but not viable one IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Please enter following code snippet in webconfig:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreservReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be your navigation properties are Interface so when you access the service it doesnt know what concrete type to use. How about change that to List see if that help?

Comment: They are no interaces.  They are the actual implemented classes

Answer (score 0):

Use Serializable() attribute.
Try this:

```
namespace Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Speciality
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SpecialityId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MedicalFacility> MedicalFacilities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end what finally worked was disabling ProxyCreationEnabled.

So in my controller I now have the following code:

```
public class SpecialitiesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public SpecialitiesController()
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        // GET: api/Specialities
        public IQueryable<Speciality> GetSpeciality()
        {
            return db.Speciality;
        }
    }
```

This does mean that I will have to eager load any navigational properties that I want to use using .include().

Comment: As I suggested you can preserve lazy loading by using DTO objects to transform entity to plain object.